# Does Hangfire's recurring jobs store the state in the case of exception for later execution attempts?

Tags: hangfire

I have a program which connects to a web service for pulling some messages.After I receive them I have no way of reading those messages again.So I decided to secure them in a persistent store to be processed by other parties.

I wrapped this *request and persist process* method in Hangfire's AddOrUpdate-cron recurring job hoping in case of exception during job execution hangfire will attempt the execute the task later with it's stored state.Is my assumption correct? I couldn't see any explanation in the documents regarding recurring job states.

In the case of delayed,recurring or fire-forget jobs does Hangfire serialize the code piece of those jobs with  their states to database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Following article answers this question and gives some information regarding how background jobs are handled.](https://www.hangfire.io/blog/2014/05/10/are-your-methods-ready-to-run-in-background.html)